# Moment invalid date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following:

```
     ...
        const dateOfBirth = moment(data.dob)
            .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        debugger
        const updatedInfo = {
            firstName: data.firstName,
            lastName: data.lastName,
            title: data.title,
            version: customerVersion,
            dateOfBirth,
            email: data.email,
        }
     ...
```

if the value of `data.dob` is 11/10/1900 it's all working, but if it's `15/11/1900` the `dateOfBirth value` is `invalid date`.

I have tried to use the following:

```
        const dateOfBirth = moment(data.dob)
            .endOf("month")
            .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

but it still returns invalid date.

[image]

Comment: looks like it's accepting "MM-DD-YYYY"-formatted dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse it with propriate format

```
moment("15/11/1900", "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```